# Monte carlo integration not working?

Tags: r, random, montecarlo

I wish to integrate `(1/y)*(2/(1+(log(y))^2))` from 0 to 1. Wolfram alpha tells me this should be pi. But when I do monte carlo integration in R, I keep getting 3.00 and 2.99 after trying over 10 times. This is what I have done:

```
y=runif(10^6)
f=(1/y)*(2/(1+(log(y))^2))
mean(f)
```

I copied the exact function into wolfram alpha to check that the integral should be [pi](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281%2Fy%29*%282%2F%281%2B%28log%28y%29%29%5E2%29%29+from+0+to+1)

I tried to check if my y is properly distributed by checking it's mean and plotting a historgram, and it seems to be ok. Could there be something wrong with my computer?

Edit: Maybe someone else could copy my code and run it themselves, to confirm that it isn't my computer acting up.

Comment: Speaking of 10 times, do you mean 10 samples? That's way too few! You should do around 1,000,000 samples. Also check out importance sampling (instead of a uniform random number distribution), that helps in decreasing the error.

Comment: It appears he/she is doing it around 10^6 samples each. I'm thinking he/she meant 10 times running the R program

Comment: I did 10^6 samples, yes. What I meant is that I ran the same code 10 times.

Comment: Not the best example of an integral to use mc methods due to the asymptote at zero - you would expect it to underestimate.

Comment: @user20650 So are my results ordinary and to be expected? The amount mc underestimates it by seems to be very consistent.

Comment: `Fx <- function(x) {(1 / x) * (2 / (1 + (log(x)) ^ 2))}; integrate(Fx, 0, 1)` returns ~3.13. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @nrussell I am not actually integrating the function in the traditional analytical sense. I am running a simulation using random numbers to approximate the integral. Normally this would be done for functions which you can't integrate analytically, but I'm just testing it out with different functions.

Comment: Well, after 10^7 samples I've got `3.125936`, so everything looks ok, more samples - better result

Comment: No, taking it back, it was some seed fluke, values like 3.0x are a lot more common

Comment: You can't estimate an [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) by MC simulation.

Comment: @Roland sure you can

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Then please post an answer demonstrating how to do that.

Comment: @Roland please read the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, first let's start with simple transformation, `log(x) -> x`, making integral

```
I = S 2/(1+x^2) dx, x in [0...infinity]
```

where `S` is integration sign.

So function 1/(1+x^2) is falling monotonically and reasonable fast. We need some reasonable PDF to sample points in [0...infinity] interval, such that most of the region where original function is significant is covered. We will use exponential distribution with some free parameter which we will use to optimize sampling.

```
I = S 2/(1+x^2)*exp(k*x)/k k*exp(-k*x) dx, x in [0...infinity]
```

So, we have k*e<sup>-kx</sup> as properly normalized PDF in the range of [0...infinity]. Function to integrate is `(2/(1+x^2))*exp(k*x)/k`. We know that sampling from exponential is basically `-log(U(0,1))`, so code to do that is very simple

```
k <- 0.05

# exponential distribution sampling from uniform vector
Fx <- function(x) {
    -log(x) / k
}

# integrand
Fy <- function(x) {
    ( 2.0 / (1.0 + x*x) )*exp(k*x) / k
}

set.seed(12345)

n <- 10^6L
s <- runif(n)

# one could use rexp() as well instead of Fx
# x <- rexp(n, k)
x <- Fx(s)

f <- Fy(x)

q <- mean(f)

print(q)
```

Result is equal to `3.145954`, for seed `22345` result is equal to `3.135632`, for seed `32345` result is equal to `3.146081`.

UPDATE

Going back to original function [0...1] is quite simple

UPDATE II

changed per prof.Bolker suggestion

Comment: since all of the functions used here are vectorized already, it would be more efficient (and readable) to use `x <- Fx(s); f <- Fy(x); q <- mean(f)`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Thanks, but do you have any idea why my original method did not work? There seems to be a bias of around -0.14 in it. Can monte carlo integration produce a biased estimate when dealing with asymptotes?

Comment: @user124249 there was no bias in method you use, just not enough importance/coverage (though I would advice to try with seeds 32345 and 31345). THere is no inherent bias when dealing with asymptotes